# No se puede establecer una conexión porque el equipo de destino la deniega

Tags: apache, wamp

Tengo un servidor apache corriendo que  cuando ejecuto un comando

```
ab -n -c 200 http://xxx.com
```

me genera el siguiente error que dice:

> apr_socket_connect(): No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión. (730061)

¿Esto por qué puede estar pasando y cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Parece un problema de permisos o de seguridad, revisa que tengas el firewall o cualquier antivirus quitado y que los puertos están bien y a ver si sigue fallando

Comment: Así es imposible que te ayudemos necesitamos más pistas que detalles tiene el log que hiciste para que te diera ese error que versión de Apache . Si estás usando https es probable que tengas que instalar unos certificados

Comment: Siguiendo lo que dice @david si tienes Skype instalsdo por alguna razón toma el puerto 80 cierra Skype e intenta

Comment: Hola Sebastian, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla). ¿Podrías añadir algo más de detalle a la pregunta? Por ejemplo, ¿qué hace ese comando? ¿cuál es la url que usas en el comando? ¿aparece algo en los logs de Apache? Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones para mejorar tus preguntas. Un saludo.